# remove a row in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database file (*.db) in which I want to remove the first row as it contains the headers. How do I do this?
My table looks like this :

```
"#RIC"  "Date[L]"   "Time[L]"   "before_or_after"   "announcement_time" "window"    "BAS"
"#RIC"  "Date[L]"   "Time[L]"   "before_or_after"   "announcement_time" "window"    "BAS"
"AFI.AX"    "20120203"  "09:56:00.000"  "before"    "10:27:00"  "-1860" "-0.0697674418604651"
"AFI.AX"    "20120203"  "09:56:05.000"  "before"    "10:27:00"  "-1855" "-0.0697674418604651"
"AFI.AX"    "20120203"  "09:56:10.000"  "before"    "10:27:00"  "-1850" "-0.0697674418604651"
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that none of the 'real' rows can have the column name in one of its column values, filter on that:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE "#RIC" = '#RIC';
```